# Setting TTL for expire data from collection

Tags: mongodb, go, ttl

Is there a correct way to configure data self-deletion by key using the [official mongo driver](http://go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver)? The only method that I found in the Mongo-driver module is [ExpireAfterSeconds](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#IndexOptionsBuilder.ExpireAfterSeconds), but I'm not sure how to use it correctly.
Here's the [repository](https://github.com/AlfredMulder/shelve) with what is ready at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an ttl index on the field which needs to be removed after n seconds.

In the below code snippet, have created an expirationTime field on which ttl can be set. After 60 seconds from the expirationTime set in the record, the record will be removed.

Following is the code to create a TTL index:

```
var ttl *int32
    *ttl = 60
    keys := bsonx.Doc{{Key: "expirationTime", Value: bsonx.Int32(int32(1))}}
    idx := mongo.IndexModel{Keys: keys, Options: &options.IndexOptions{ExpireAfterSeconds: ttl}}
    _, err := collection.Indexes().CreateOne(context.Background(), idx)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error occurred while creating index", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Index creation success")
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you can use it. The create index part should be done once in the Init() or main method. If the requirement is to delete the record after the ExpirationDate, you can set the value of ttl as 0 and when inserting the record, set the expiration date accordingly. Once the clock time reaches the expirationDate value, the record will be removed.